# Async & Performance example in "You Don't Know JS"

Tags: javascript

Everytime I try to read "You don't know JS", I run into examples where I can't seem to understand if it's a mistake by the author or JS is really that mind blowing. Consider this example under "Parallel threads" in the chapter "Async & Performance":

```
var a = 20;

function foo() {
    a = a + 1;
}

function bar() {
    a = a * 2;
}

// ajax(..) is some arbitrary Ajax function given by a library
ajax( "http://some.url.1", foo );
ajax( "http://some.url.2", bar );
```

Then the author proceeds with the following explanation:

> In JavaScript's single-threaded behavior, if `foo()` runs before `bar()`,
>   the result is that a has 42, but if `bar()` runs before `foo()` the result
>   in a will be 41.

How can it be that, if `foo()` gets run first, the result is 41? I tried this example many times in the console, and I always get 21 following this logic:

1. We declare a var with the integer value of 20.
2. We write functions `foo()` and `bar()`. In foo, we say 'Set the var of `a` to be `a + 1` i.e. 20 + 1'.
3. Then we call them with arbitrary Ajax function. If `foo()` gets called first, the result is 21, not 41.

Am I wrong and just plain stupid for missing out something?

Comment: Add a `console.log` in your functions body, my guess is that `bar` is never called

Comment: If `foo()` is called first - `bar()` is called second. In any situation, both functions will be call

Comment: He's looking at the result after both functions are called, not the result after `foo` is called.

Comment: Re-read what Kyle wrote: if `foo()` runs first, the result is **42**, not 41. `foo()` runs, and `a` is now 21. Then `bar()` runs, and `a` is now 42, because `2*21` is 42.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ajax(...)` is an async call. The code is actually making 2 async calls.

## Possibility A : `foo()` is executed first

`foo()` : `20 = 20 + 1; //a = 21`

`bar()` : `21 = 21 * 2; //a = 42`

## Possibility B : `bar()` is executed first

`bar()` : `20 = 20 * 2; //a = 40`

`foo()` : `40 = 40 + 1; //a = 41`

### *Note*

In both cases, `bar()` **AND** `foo()` will be called

### Explanation

> In JavaScript's single-threaded behavior, if foo() runs before bar(),
> the result is that a has 42, but if bar() runs before foo() the result
> in a will be 41.

The result used in the sentence is the result **after both function execution**

Comment: Excellent, dankeschön all!

Answer (score 2):

If foo() is being called first :

```
a = 20
// foo() called
a = 20 + 1 = 21
// bar() called
a = 21 * 2 = 42
```

If bar() is being called first :

```
a = 20
// bar() called
a = 20 * 2 = 40
// foo() called
a = 40  + 1 = 41
```

Comment: Please replace "ends" with "is called".

Answer (score 2):

Foo gets called first and the value increases a to 21. Bar still gets called, which multiplies the global variable a which is now 21 * 2 = 42. It comes down to two simple expressions.

```
foo(); bar(); // (20 + 1) * 2 = 42
bar(); foo(); // (20 * 2) + 1 = 41
```